# two ggplot2 previous to transform to plotly to obtain interactive

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

I have two ggplot2 that I want to transform to ggplotly with the idea of interaction between both figures.
The problem is that the DF for the second needs a transformation. I know how to do it with plotly from scratch but I need do it from ggplot2.

Here is my code:

```
require(dplyr)
require(lubridate)
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)
require(plotly)
```

My data:

```
df1<-tibble(date=seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"),as.Date("2003-12-31"),by="1 month"),
           value=sample(10:20,48,replace = TRUE))

df2<-df1 %>% mutate(year=year(date))

df3<-df2 %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
    summarise(max=max(value),mean=mean(value),min=min(value))
```

This is the final output with `ggplot2` without interaction

```
graf1<-ggplot(df2)+geom_line(aes(date,value,color=factor(year),group=year),size=4)

graf2<-ggplot(df3)+
          geom_segment(aes(x=year,xend=year,y=min,yend=max,color=factor(year),group=year),size=10)+
          geom_point(aes(year,mean),size=2)

grid.arrange(graf1,graf2,nrow=2)
```

This is the my proposal to do it from ggplot2 to ggplotly (and doesn't work)

```
df2Linked<-highlight_key(df2,~year)

graf1<-ggplot(df2Linked)+geom_line(aes(date,value,color=factor(year),group=year),size=4)
graf1Ly<-ggplotly(graf1)%>% highlight(on = "plotly_hover", off = "plotly_deselect")
#it works!!

#**that NOT WORK in this way**, as its an object of class "c('SharedData', 'R6')"
df3<-df2Linked %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(max=max(value),mean=mean(value),min=min(value))

graf2<-ggplot(df3)+geom_segment(aes(x=year,xend=year,y=min,yend=max,color=factor(year),group=year),size=10)+geom_point(aes(year,mean),size=2)
graf2Ly<-ggplotly(graf2)%>% highlight(on = "plotly_hover", off = "plotly_deselect")

subplot(graf1Ly,graf2Ly,nrows=2)
```

How has to be done it?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use `ggplotly()` in each plot and than use `subplot()` from `plotly`

This isn't the pretty plot ever, but I think that it will help you:

```
graf1<-ggplot(df2)+
        geom_line(aes(date,value,color=factor(year),group=year),size=4) + 
        labs(color='Year') 

graf2<-ggplot(df3)+
          geom_segment(aes(x=year,xend=year,y=min,yend=max,color=factor(year),group=year),size=10)+
          geom_point(aes(year,mean),size=2) + 
          labs(color='Year')



subplot(ggplotly(graf1),ggplotly(graf2), nrows = 2)
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: thanks, but in this way there is only interaction througth the legend. I would like to use "highlight_key" or similar that I click in the graph something reacts in the other graphs

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you can try specify in each plot the `legend_group` the things you want put in `highlight_key`. But I don´t have sure about it.